# Recursive hierarchical query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have below table

TblMatrix

```
ID   ApproverId
--------------------
1    4
2    7
7    8
4    5
5    6
```

I want to write a self join query to return below output for any ApproverId

If I pass ApproverId As 6

Output should be

```
ID
---
5
4
1
```

If I pass ApproverId As 8

Output should be

```
ID
---
7
2
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  By the way, "self join" does not describe your question as well as "recursive hierarchical query."

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using SQL server 2012 R2

Comment: This question is related to parent children condition not self join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursive query

```
with rcte as
(
    select id from tblMatrix where approverId = 8
    union all
    select tblMatrix.id 
    from tblMatrix
    join rcte on tblMatrix.approverid = rcte.id
)
select * from rcte
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=17db9665ffb7298e3451f91c898c97bd)